# What's causing this massive negative space?

Tags: css

The problem I have is very specific and quite hard to detail unless you have a mobile device.

I've been working on making my website responsive recently and on desktop it works pretty well. I've just had a few people test it on mobile (Android and Windows Phone) and they're telling me that there's quite a lot of negative space, as if it's zoomed out.

Looking at my code, I have no idea why this is happening. Can anyone perhaps enlighten me?

[Here is the question](http://www.tomdwyerdesign.com)

Comment: Should the site fill the mobile browser and not have the space top/left/right/bottom ?

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=619" />` is probably the culprit, you are making the mobile screen, no matter what size, size the website to 619px. try `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`

Comment: have you set a viewport meta tag? -like andy said

Comment: It should have  tiny amount of padding on all sides, like 3-4px.

Comment: Probably wanna look at the margin/padding at the top when your media queries activate too

Comment: @TomDwyer NP, gotta help fellow FCET'ers ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your viewport tag to something like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```